# Issues Building .NET 8 MAUI in Github Runners

Tags: github-actions, maui

I've got a new MAUI project and I'm trying to set up a basic CI pipeline for it.

I've got this as my workflow definition:

```yaml
name: MAUI Continuous Integration

on:
  pull_request: 
    branches:
      - master
  push:
    branches:
      - master
        
jobs:        
  build-android:
    name: "Build Android"
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: 8.0.x
      - name: Install MAUI Workloads
        run: |
          dotnet workload install maui
          dotnet workload install android
      - name: Restore Dependencies
        run: dotnet restore ./src/OpenEqiSports/OpenEqiSports.csproj
      - name: Build Android
        run: dotnet build ./src/OpenEqiSports/OpenEqiSports.csproj  -c Release -f net8.0-android --no-restore
      - name: Upload Android Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: OpenEqiSports-Android
          path: ./src/OpenEqiSports/bin/Release/net8.0-android/*Signed.a*
          
  build-windows:
    name: "Build Windows"
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: 8.0.x
      - name: Install MAUI Workloads
        run: dotnet workload install maui
      - name: Restore Dependencies
        run: dotnet restore ./src/OpenEqiSports/OpenEqiSports.csproj
      - name: Build Windows
        run: dotnet build ./src/OpenEqiSports/OpenEqiSports.csproj -c Release -f net8.0-windows --no-restore
      - name: Upload Windows Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: OpenEqiSports-Windows
          path: ./src/OpenEqiSports/bin/Release/net8.0-windows*/**/OpenEqiSports*.msix   

  build-ios:
    name: "Build iOS"
    runs-on: macos-14
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Select Xcode 15.2
        run: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_15.1.app/Contents/Developer
      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: 8.0.x
      - name: Install MAUI Workloads
        run: |
          dotnet workload install maui
          dotnet workload install ios
      - name: Restore Dependencies
        run: dotnet restore ./src/OpenEqiSports/OpenEqiSports.csproj
      - name: Build iOS
        run: dotnet build ./src/OpenEqiSports/OpenEqiSports.csproj -c Release -f net8.0-ios --no-restore
      - name: Upload iOS Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: OpenEqiSports-iOS
          path: ./src/OpenEqiSports/bin/Release/net8.0-ios/**/*.app/
          
  build-maccatalyst:
    name: "Build MacCatalyst"
    runs-on: macos-14
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Select Xcode 15.2
        run: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_15.1.app/Contents/Developer
      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: 8.0.x
      - name: Install MAUI Workloads
        run: |
          dotnet workload install maui
          dotnet workload install maccatalyst
      - name: Restore Dependencies
        run: dotnet restore ./src/OpenEqiSports/OpenEqiSports.csproj
      - name: Build MacCatalyst
        run: dotnet build ./src/OpenEqiSports/OpenEqiSports.csproj -c Release -f net8.0-maccatalyst --no-restore
      - name: Upload MacCatalyst Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: OpenEqiSports-MacCatalyst
          path: ./src/OpenEqiSports/bin/Release/net8.0-maccatalyst/**/*.app/
```

(Yes, I know this needs refactoring)

And my csproj looks like:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFrameworks>

        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>OpenEqiSports</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>OpenEqiSports</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.hughesjs.openeqisports</ApplicationId>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">17,2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">15.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">24.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.22621.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.22621.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.png" Resize="True" BaseSize="300,185" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.BLE" Version="3.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Now, this successfully builds the Android and iOS versions and the others fail with:

Windows:

> MSBuild version 17.8.3+195e7f5a3 for .NET Error:
> C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(215,5):
> error NETSDK1135: SupportedOSPlatformVersion 10.0.22621.0 cannot be
> higher than TargetPlatformVersion 7.0.
> [D:\a\OpenEQiSports\OpenEQiSports\src\OpenEqiSports\OpenEqiSports.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-windows]

This just has me bamboozled, dotnet 8 is installed so what's the issue?

MacCatalyst:

> Error:
> /Users/runner/.dotnet/sdk/8.0.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5):
> error NETSDK1047: Assets file
> '/Users/runner/work/OpenEQiSports/OpenEQiSports/src/OpenEqiSports/obj/project.assets.json'
> doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-maccatalyst/maccatalyst-x64'. Ensure
> that restore has run and that you have included 'net8.0-maccatalyst'
> in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include
> 'maccatalyst-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.
> [/Users/runner/work/OpenEQiSports/OpenEQiSports/src/OpenEqiSports/OpenEqiSports.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-maccatalyst]

I have the target framework set...

What's going on here? It all builds fine locally (well, I can't test the Windows one as I'm on a mac, but the rest builds). How can I get this going?

Answer (score 0):

The issues here were legion:

## MacCatalyst

Due to MacOS running on both Arm64 and x64 in a decent proportion, it wouldn't make sense to assume a Runtime ID. As such, I needed to specify the runtime for each and build for each separately. This is done with the `--runtime <RID>` flag on `dotnet build`. I coupled that with a matrix so the relevant section of the yml now looks like:

```yaml
  build-maccatalyst:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        runtime: [maccatalyst-arm64, maccatalyst-x64]
    name: "Build MacCatalyst (${{ matrix.runtime }})"
#    needs: run-tests
    runs-on: macos-14
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Select Xcode 15.2
        run: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_15.1.app/Contents/Developer
      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: 8.0.x
      - name: Install MAUI Workloads
        run: |
          dotnet workload install maui
          dotnet workload install maccatalyst
      - name: Restore Dependencies
        run: dotnet restore ./src/OpenEqiSports/OpenEqiSports.csproj
      - name: Build MacCatalyst
        run: dotnet build ./src/OpenEqiSports/OpenEqiSports.csproj -c Release -f net8.0-maccatalyst --no-restore --runtime ${{ matrix.runtime }}
      - name: Upload MacCatalyst Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: OpenEqiSports-${{ matrix.runtime }}
          path: ./src/OpenEqiSports/bin/Release/net8.0-maccatalyst/**/*.app/
```

## Windows

So dotnet 8 has a minimum target framework of `net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0`.

So in the csproj we need:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.19041.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.19041.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

Unfortunately, there [seems to be a bug in dotnet 8](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/37118) that also causes weird issues when building, so working around that takes a `--self-contained` build.

This makes the CI section look like:

```yaml
  build-windows:
    name: "Build Windows"
#    needs: run-tests
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: 8.0.x
      - name: Install MAUI Workloads
        run: dotnet workload install maui
      - name: Build Windows
        run: dotnet build ./src/OpenEqiSports/OpenEqiSports.csproj -c Release -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0 --self-contained
      - name: Upload Windows Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: OpenEqiSports-Windows
          path: ./src/OpenEqiSports/bin/Release/net8.0-windows*/**/OpenEqiSports*.msix
```